# RewriteCond a sub domain and folder to querystring

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to do an htaccess RewriteCond that takes any sub domain and any sub directory and rewrites them to the query string. So

```
http://somesub.domain.com/somefolder
```

becomes

```
http://domain.com/app.php?sub=somesub&folder=somefolder
```

I also want `http://www.domain.com` to go unchanged (i.e. to index.htm).

I've got the sub domain part working, but can't get the folder part to work with it

This is what I have for the sub domain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://domain.com/app.php?sub=%1 [P,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use back reference of captured group from `RewriteRule`:

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://domain.com/app.php?sub=%1&folder=$1 [P,L,QSA]
```